# Laravel testing

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm currently testing a Laravel 5.5 package. The problem that is that when I try this:

```
this->post('/under/check', ['code' => 1235]);
```

The response is always page not found! When I try this in postman it's working and I receive a proper response?!?!

What could I be doing wrong?

It's an open source project so it's on github:

https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction

Comment: If this is PhP, `this` should be `$this`. Idk if that is the problem or just a mistake when copy and pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You routes file should have this route mentioned something like this.

```
Route::post('/under/check','SomeController@someMethod');
```

Make sure your Route is post and not get

Comment: I've done that https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction/blob/master/src/UnderConstructionServiceProvider.php